# How can i show $\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} \cot(\frac{k\pi}{2m}) = 1$ where $m$ is an integer greater than 1

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, products

Show that $$\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} \cot(\frac{k\pi}{2m}) = 1,$$ where $m$ is an integer greater than 1

I think it can be solved by nth root theorem but I don't get the answer :c

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\;\; \cos \frac{k \pi}{2m} = \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{k \pi}{2m}\right) = \sin \frac{(m-k) \pi}{2m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$\tan{x}\cot{x}=1$$
and
$$\tan{x}=\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right).$$
I think it should help.

Comment: It helped, thanks :D